# php loop through multiple arrays with same key

Tags: php, database, for-loop, foreach, drupal-7

How can I go about getting these results to insert into a database as one record for each key name?
These 2 arrays will always have the same number of records and key names.

```
[size_chart_data] =Array (
    [Width] =Array (
        [Small] =18
        [Medium] =20
        [Large] =22
        [X-Large] =24
        [2X-Large] =26
        [3X-Large] =28
        [4X-Large] =30
        [5X-Large] =32
    )
    [Height] =Array (
        [Small] =28
        [Medium] =29
        [Large] =30
        [X-Large] =31
        [2X-Large] =32
        [3X-Large] =33
        [4X-Large] =34
        [5X-Large] =35
    )
)
```

I am using the following sql to insert into the database:

```
$chartData = db_insert('pa_size_chart_data')
    ->fields(array(
      'width',
      'height',
    ));
```

Thank you so much for your time. Please let me know if anything needs clarification.
Aaron

Comment: What is `size_id`?

Comment: size_id is unimportant for this question and I have edited the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer. Very special thank you to @u_mulder and @blackandorangecat for all of your helpful thoughts!!!
In the question I only included width and height. But I felt it could be more helpful for others if I included a 3rd level. So the answer includes width, height, & sleeve.

```
  $size_chart_data = array();
  foreach ($size_chart_data['Width'] as $key => $value) {
      // floatval() is changing string results to float
      $value = floatval($value);

      if (!empty($size_chart_data['Height']) && !empty($size_chart_data['Sleeve'])) {
        // floatval() is changing string results to float
        $size_chart_data['Height'][$key] = floatval($size_chart_data['Height'][$key]);
        $size_chart_data['Sleeve'][$key] = floatval($size_chart_data['Sleeve'][$key]);
        $db_data = array(
            'width' => $value,                             // this is width 
            'height' => $size_chart_data['Height'][$key],  // this is height
            'sleeve' => $size_chart_data['Sleeve'][$key],  // this is the sleeve
        );
      } elseif (!empty($size_chart_data['Height'])) {
        $size_chart_data['Height'][$key] = floatval($size_chart_data['Height'][$key]);
        $db_data = array(
            'width' => $value,                             // this is width 
            'height' => $size_chart_data['Height'][$key],  // this is height
            'sleeve' => null,                              // this is the sleeve
        );  
      } elseif (!empty($size_chart_data['Width'])){
        $db_data = array(
            'width' => $value,  // this is width 
            'height' => null,   // this is height
            'sleeve' => null,   // this is the sleeve
        );
      }            
        $sizeArr = array($db_data);
        $chartData = db_insert('pa_size_chart_data')
          ->fields(array(
            'width',
            'height',
            'sleeve',
          ));
        foreach ($sizeArr as $sizeRec) {
          $chartData->values($sizeRec);
        }
        $chartData->execute();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should do this:

```
$size_chart_data = array();
foreach ($size_chart_data['Width'] as $key => $value) {
    $db_data = array();
    if (!empty($size_chart_data['Height'][$key])) {
        $db_data = array(
            'size_id' => $key,                             // this is size_id
            'width' => $value,                             // this is width 
            'height' => $size_chart_data['Height'][$key],  // this is height
        );
        // check what you've got
        print_r($db_data);
        // add $db_data to database, I suppose it's like
        $chartData = db_insert('pa_size_chart_data')
            ->fields($db_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you U_Mulder!
It's putting the data into an order that will be usable. For some reason the data is not getting inserted into the database. I'll do some more investigation and hopefully be able to figure it out.

Comment: Perhaps it's not usable because it's a multidimensional array? @aaronb

Comment: `$singleArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $multiArray);` @aaronb  this will flatten the array. You could try this before inserting into the db

Comment: Thanks for your idea! I've went round and round trying to make use of the function you suggested. Can you show me how you would use it in this particular example? Thank you!
@blackandorangecat

Comment: Well if you want to see what the function does, put this right after `print_r($db_data); `$db_data_flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $db_data); print_r($db_data_flat)` and then change the value inside of "fields" to $db_data_flat. @aaronb I'm not sure if this will fix it, but it's an idea

Comment: Also, use this for your print statements. Print "<pre>"; print_r($nameOfArray); print "</pre>";

Comment: I am getting this error:
Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in
@blackandorangecat

Comment: So maybe the loop up above is not even adding anything to the array.. You could put a print statement insids the loop to see if it's doing anything